# how to get deployment-id of api in aws apigateway from console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Hi I am trying **aws apigateway create-stage command**, I need deployment-id to create a new stage because it is **[Required]** option.

I cant find deployment-id on console.

I have already created 2 stages(from Actions--> DeployApi) from console.
Where to find deployment-id?
is it available on console or not?

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You sholuld be able to see a deployment-id by using the `get-deployments` method in the cli.

`aws apigateway get-deployments --rest-api-id 1234123412`

In the output the `id` value is the `deployment-id`

[AWS CLI Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-deployments.html)

Comment: I guess depolyment-id can't be found on console, Thanks for reply. When I used this command I got an array of objects (e.g. { id:"xxx", createdDate:1539178484}). Can we see all these deployments on console?

Comment: I updated my response to be more specific, sorry for the confusion. The `id` is actually the `deployment-id`. To see more details about a specific deployment the `aws apigateway get-deployment --rest-api-id 1234123412 --deployment-id ztt4m2`